# Why are orders formalized by weak inequalities?

Tags: notation, order-theory

Partial orders are formalized by weak inequalities $\geq$ rather than strict ones $>$. We then add an additional axiom which says that $x\geq y\land y\geq x$ implies $x=y$.

But it seems to me that we can instead speak of strict inequalities, and replace that axiom with the axiom that $x>y\implies \neg y>x$, and that $\neg x>x$.

I am not claiming that this is “better”, just that it seems a bit more intuitive to me at first glance. **Why has it been chosen to formalize orders according to weak inequalities, rather than strict ones?**

Comment: As far as I know, orders can be and are viewed both ways. In many instances, the weak inequality is simpler to define than the strict inequality. For example, in defining the order of cardinal numbers: $|X|\le|Y|$ means that there is an injection from $X$ to $Y$, $|X|\lt|Y|$ means that there is an injection from $X$ to $Y$ but there is no injection from $Y$ to $X$. Another example, $X\subseteq Y$ means that every element of $X$ is an element of $Y$, $X\subsetneq Y$ means that every element of $X$ is an element of $Y$ and at least one element of $Y$ is not an element of $X$.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that there is the related notion of a [*preorder*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preorder), which is a reflexive and transitive binary relation. An antisymmetric preorder is a partial order. Furthermore, if $\leqslant$ is a preorder on $X$, then the relation $\sim$ defined by
$$
a \sim b \iff a \leqslant b\text{ and } b \leqslant a
$$ 
is an equivalence relation, and the preorder $\leqslant$ induces a partial order on the set $X/{\sim}$. This construction often occurs in mathematics.

As one cannot use $<$ to define a preorder, the notation $\leqslant$ is preferred, even for an order.